Freezing problem 24.04
I'm wondering why it's freezing usually when I tried to work on MySQL Workbench, but a while ago when it went to freezing I went to tty mode and tried to kill the process of MySQL. Then I tried to run startx to go back to the GUI, but then there was this problem.

After rebooting it's working fine again. I'm just concerned that maybe it will break. Is there anyway to avoid this freezing problem?
